# Why do my clones of Bootstrap Selectpicker create additional dropdowns?

Tags: clone, bootstrap-selectpicker, dropdownchecklist

Have created a checklist table with multiple dropdowns using Bootstrap Selectpicker but when I clone the table for some reason a second dropdown appears in the first cell. Been playing around with this for days as I'm sure it's my JQuery or something to do with the initialisation of the select...I think.

```
$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

I ran into issues at the start with cloning classes so ended up cloning data-* attributes which seem to work better, still can't fix this issue though.

All help appreciated.

Snippet of the table

https://jsfiddle.net/tyt06sfd/33/

Answer (score 0):

To cut a long story short, I created a new form without using bootstrap selectpicker. Was much easier to create and maintain using HTML, CSS and JQuery.